# WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/SpringTest/add] in DispatcherServlet with name telusuko

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller, frameworks, servlet-3.0

Error geting:

Mar 03, 2017 7:06:58 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/SpringTest/add] in DispatcherServlet with name 'telusuko'

Calling from this

http://localhost:8085/SpringTest/index.jsp url works fine.

http://localhost:8085/SpringTest/add?t1=dfvd&t2=vdfvfd not working 404 error getting

AddController:

```
package com.springs;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class AddController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/add")
    public String add(){

      return "display.jsp";
     //System.out.println("work");  
    }
}
```

telusuko-servlet.xml

```
 <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:ctx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans       
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd     
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc      
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd      
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context      
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd ">
    <ctx:annotation-config></ctx:annotation-config>
    <ctx:component-scan base-package="com.springs"></ctx:component-scan>
    </beans>
```

Web.xml

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>
  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>

  <servlet>
       <servlet-name>telusuko</servlet-name>
       <servlet-class>
       org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
       </servlet-class>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>telusuko</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

index.jsp:

```
<html>
<body>
<h2>Hello World!</h2>

<form action="add">
<input type="text" name="t1" />
<input type="text" name="t2" />
<input type="submit" />

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are creating your packages and classes in  'src/main/**java**' and  **NOT** in  'src/main/**resources**'

Answer (score 0):

That is usually happening when in your dispatcher-servel.xml this is missing

```
 

<bean
class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
<propertyname="prefix">
```

Check chapter 6 of this link

https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/spring/mvc/spring-mvc-view-resolver-example/

Comment: No use any other suggestions ?

Comment: Try to remove ".Jsp" from the return and print me on the comment the URL after the submit

Comment: i was written and tried with system.out.println instead of jsp file even not working. DispatcherServlet unable to find configured class with @Controller

Comment: Can you print the URL on click please?

Comment: unable to understand

Comment: How this controller is getting called? You may have a Jsp no? Is this controller get called from a click? From a form?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137207/discussion-between-srinivas-and-oeh).

Answer (score 0):

- Re-create the project with Dynamic web project.
- After that right click on project, go to configure and choose "convert to MAVEN project".